# query data for high-frequency rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm a novice to SQL. I'm trying to group data by app version, and only show the two most popular app versions per operating system.

Let's say I have the following columns:

- operating_system - varchar
- app_version - varchar
- start_time - float
- timestamp - timestamp

I can do the following to get the average start time by OS, app version, and day, but I only want the top two or three app versions in that time range.

```
SELECT operation_system, app_version, DATE(timestamp) as date, AVG(start_time) as average_start_time
FROM ...
WHERE timestamp > timestamp_sub(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY operating_system, app_version, date
ORDER BY operating_system, app_version DESC, date
```

but I only want the top two app versions per OS where there may be dozens. And using `LIMIT`, I believe, would only cap the final total. Is there a good way to only get the two or three most frequent per app version?

Here's an example table without the timestamp:

| operating_system | app_version | start_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Windows | 1.23 | 7 |
| Windows | 1.22 | 9 |
| OS X | 7.0 | 4 |
| Windows | 1.22 | 16 |
| Windows | 1.23 | 8 |
| Windows | 1.21 | 4 |

And here's an example response getting the top-two (by frequency) app versions per OS:

| operating_system | app_version | average_start_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Windows | 1.23 | 7.5 |
| Windows | 1.22 | 12.5 |
| OS X | 7.0 | 4 |

In this example, the row of Windows 1.21 is omitted, but because it had fewer rows than Windows 1.22 or 1.23.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your qustion

Comment: when follow above comments, please don't forget provide logic you have in mind. for example - what is notion of top N? top by what? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
select * except(cnt) from (
  select operating_system, app_version, avg(start_time) average_start_time, count(*) cnt
  from your_table
  group by operating_system, app_version
)
qualify 2 >= row_number() over(partition by operating_system order by cnt desc)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]